# gem and/or Ruby on Rails broke all of a sudden, anyone know what happened?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I had a Ruby on Rails app that used to work.  I hadn't used it in a month or so, but then tried starting it up today with `rails s` and got the following error—in fact, I get this error when I try `rails -h` or `rails -v` or even `gem -h` or `sudo gem update --system` or anything having to do with `gem`.

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/specifications/json-1.5.1.gemspec:10.
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:277:in `_resort!': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:276:in `sort!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:276:in `_resort!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:270:in `_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:402:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Anyone know what's going on and how to fix it? How can I uninstall it all and reinstall it (without uninstalling my OS, man that would really suck)

Comment: Also, I ran "sudo gem update rails" right before this broke, even though I had already installed rails.  (I wanted to update it.) I'm guessing that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd try cleaning out all your installed gems by running

```
rm -rf ~/.gems
sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/*
```

After this `gem list` should list no gems. Then run

```
sudo gem update --system
```

to ensure Ruby Gems is at the latest version. You'll then have to reinstall all your gems. (Probably `gem install bundler` followed by `bundle install`).

By the way, you should check out [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io) for managing Ruby versions and keeping all your development gems separate from the system Ruby.

Comment: I wish I could keep upvoting this every time it saves my ass!

Comment: `sudo gem pristine --all` does rebuild your gems, which could be enough as well.

Comment: ```Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0```

Answer (score 0):

`gem update --system` should fix you up. That will install the latest version of RubyGems.

Comment: Uh oh, it looks like I must've broken gem... the same thing happens when I run gem update --system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with XCode 4.3. Try this:

> Open XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Install Command Line Tools

Finally run in the terminal:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with jquery-rails 2.0.3:

```
Invalid gemspec in [C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-2.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-08-16 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

To fix that, I have edited the file C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/jquery-rails-2.0.3.gemspec and change the line containing:

```
s.date = %q{2012-08-16 00:00:00.000000000Z}
```

to

```
s.date = %q{2012-08-16}
```

then it works again.