# Gem not working after update to OS X 10.10 Yosemite Beta

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have trouble getting gem to work after updating to 10.10 Yosemite.

Running this (or any other gem install / uninstall):

```
sudo gem install mysql2psql
```

And it would always give me the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    deadlock; recursive locking

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601:in `load_yaml'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `configuration'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:63:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601:in `load_yaml'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Maybe someone can help! Xcode 6 beta installed including command line tools.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue, and solved it by deleting my Gems, and reinstalling:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/*;
sudo gem update --system
```

(as described 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700776/gem-and-or-ruby-on-rails-broke-all-of-a-sudden-anyone-know-what-happened))